# combobox in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, combobox, primefaces

I am trying to learn JSF and was using JSF 2.0 along with PrimeFaces 3.0.Its cool but I was surprised to see there is no combo box.[This is the drop down they have](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprSelect.jsf).Is there any way I can get combo box as most of the users prefer to type something and aid them as well.I remember seeing a combobox in ExtJs now merged with Sensha.Is there a component like [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html) in Primefaces coming or we should develop such components.

PS:The AJAX implementation is top notch,would recommend to any one looking for using JSF for development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3.1 has editable selectOneMenu. I believe this is what you are looking for.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1631

Comment: I also prefer to have a control like this. The primefaces select one menu, we have to start typing or click to get a list of available options. In primefaces select one listbox, It is difficult to use the keyboard to navigate to the intended option. In a VB 6 combobox, for example, there is space to type letters, and a complete or partial list of available options are visible immediately below. As the user types, the available options narrows down to match the user input. This behaviour can be simulated if we use a inputtext and a list, but better to have a standard primefaces UI Component.

Answer (score 2):

Try to ask this question at the [Primefaces support forum](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=db9313ec2d5327436bf3789498f3dd85). They also have an [issue tracking site](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) with the option for new feature requests.

Or, if you are lucky, Cagatay (the Primefaces developer) visits SO from time to time and you get an answer from himself.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf